# If @before executes after constructor, how do you initialize the class?

Tags: java, constructor, junit4, oracle-adf

I am preparing some JUnit tests in Oracle ADF and I am getting surprised because I am seeing that constructor of the tested class is executed before the @before setup() method...

The issue is the constructor needs initialized variables that I was setting to constructor from the setup method... And logically I always get a beautiful NullPointerException...

The only solution I can see is initialize variables directly from the constructor, but I see that very ugly

Any idea? Thanks in advance guys

Comment: NullPointerExpection is beautiful? O.o

Comment: Unclear what this means. The constructor of the test class itself can't execute after a method is called. The constructor of another class is called when you call it. You're calling it somewhere else earlier. Debug and find out where by setting a breakpoint in that constructor.

Comment: I don't normally use a constructor in test classes.  A test class is mostly just a place to put all your test methods.  JUnit will create an object of that class (maybe it creates more than one, I don't know for sure), but this "object" is something the rest of your program shouldn't have to know about.  So why would you need a constructor?  Either this is a pretty uncommon use case, or you're not using JUnit the way it's intended.

Comment: I mean the constructor of the class whose methods I am testing.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I was talking ironically...

Comment: @AlexAcc You wouldn't put `@Before` in that class.  I don't think JUnit would find it anyway.  JUnit runs on a test class (or a suite of test classes), and it looks for annotated methods like `@Test` or `@Before` in that class(es).  As far as I know, it won't look for annotated methods in other classes, including the "classes under test".  I don't even think JUnit knows what classes are being tested.

Comment: @AlexAcc, was I serious? :D

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use JUnit's [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation.

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization. Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class. The @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those the current class.

[@Before](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html):

> When writing tests, it is common to find that several tests need similar objects created before they can run. Annotating a public void method with @Before causes that method to be run before the Test method. The @Before methods of superclasses will be run before those of the current class.

Comment: I tried @beforeClass but it must be static method setup(), and then I cannot access methods of the Class to be tested

Comment: Why do you call test methods from a setup method? That's where the annotation @Test is for. Maybe you should explain what you're really want to do in your question.

Comment: @AlexAcc A constructor is supposed to handle initialisation of private data structures. Maybe you should move the `@Before` code into the constructor or make some fields static and use `@BeforeClass`. Your design pattern seems to have a flaw there.

Answer (score 1):

@BeforeClass will be executed before constructor call; the sequence is

1. @BeforeClass
2. Construcor call
3. @Before
4. @Test